# Nodejs send post to admin-ajax.php in wordpress /getting 400 error and 0

Tags: php, node.js, ajax, wordpress

i want to post to wordpress on nodejs using admin-ajax.php which set some actions to use.
But i get statusCode:400 and 0, i don't know so much about wordpress and ajax. I tried use a cookie from the worked project from wordpress that what i want to transfer nodejs
How can i set up this?

```
const https = require("https");

const data = {
  action: "create_chapter",
  postID: "2676",
  chapterName: "2",
  chapterContent: "test",
};

const options = {
  hostname: "www.website.com",
  path: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Cookie": "cookies",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  },
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
  res.on("data", (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
  
});
req.on("error", (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});

req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest Changes:
added wordpress_logged_in to cookie,
changed req.write to req.write(data);
added content type: urlencoded and change data to url encoded

Answer (score 0):

To make ajax work in wordpress you need to instruct wordpress about what it should do when he receive your ajax request.

To do so you need to use something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_chapter', 'create_chapter' );
```

if you need that to work for non-logged in user you need this in addition:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_create_chapter', 'create_chapter' );
```

the "nopriv" just means it's open for everyone. You need to paste this code into your current active theme functions.php file or in a custom plugin you could make.

After you called the "add_action" you just need to create a function like
this:

```
function create_chapter(){
   // Code goes here
}
```

The 400 error and 0 response usually means wordpress didn't find any action to fire so it just gives that error

If you want to learn more just read the [full documentation from the wordpress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I looked codes and i can't find the add_action for chapter but when create a new chapter on wp-admin the theme send a admin-ajax request for creating new chapter using action: create_chapter.

Comment: I found the action is in the plugin of theme. But i tried everythings still get 400

Comment: If you are trying to call the AJAX action created by some third party plugin/theme it's harder to help you because they might have added some more controls on that action or they just don't fire it in the frontend